# Jagged edges on mesh

Tags: edges

Im making a combat knife in blender 2.83.

I have an issue with my mesh that I don't know how to fix without recreating the blade. The issue at hand is that when mirror modifier is turned on it creates jagged issues on the blade edge. I've tried removing the problem faces, moving vertices, checking normals and see if anything is stretching.

The only thing I haven't done yet is smoothing my mesh. Does this have an impact when baking high poly to low poly?

[image]

Comment: ... to play a bit with Merge Limit? Or isn't that just view artefact? DO you see it in render as well?

Comment: Played around with merge limit: no change and artifacts are still there. it also shows in renderer so i think mirror is the issue here but i dont know how to fix it. i can upload a blend file if that helps.

Comment: Solved the problem. It was no issues with the mirror modifier but the clipping distance was way off. hope this might help someone who has similar issues.